# JSON characters encoding

Tags: php, json

I have some European Charactacter in mySQL database table. My JSON code returns null object for those. I have also defined the header and utf8 encode still the result is null. I have attached my code snippets here

Header:

```
header("Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=utf-8");
```

JSON encoding

```
while ( $aRow = mysql_fetch_array( $rResult ) )
{
    $row = array();
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
    {
        if ( $aColumns[$i] == "version" )
        {
            /* Special output formatting for 'version' column */
            $row[] = ($aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ]=="0") ? '-' : $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
        }
        else if ( $aColumns[$i] != ' ' )
        {
            /* General output */
            $row[] = $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
        }
    }
    $output['aaData'][] = $row;
}

echo utf8_encode(json_encode( $output ));
```

JSON results in the firebug:

```
{"sEcho":1,"iTotalRecords":"190458","iTotalDisplayRecords":"4","aaData":[["University of Toronto ","Canada","72","17","41","144","7","16","6"],["The University of British Columbia ","Canada","71","22","44","176","11","16","7"],["University of Calgary","Canada","65","31","45","145","11","15","6"],[null,"Canada","63","18","45","125","12","26","6"]]}
```

Here in the JSON result one field is null in the name of University since the name of the university is in European characters.

Comment: `utf8_encode()` isn't a function that will magically fix your output...

Comment: did you try `echo json_encode(utf8_encode( $output ));`?

Comment: @Umbrella Yes, I tried that way but it gave me the whole json result null

Comment: have you set the mysql to utf8 also?  mysql_query("set character_set_results='utf8'")

Comment: You need to be dealing with utf8 all the way through.

Comment: @shapeshifter I set my mysql table to utf8 -- UTF-8 Unicode characterset also the problem is the same

Answer (score 0):

Finally I get my answer fixed by changing this

```
        $row[] = $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
```

into

```
    $row[] = utf8_encode($aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ]);
```

I encode the the whole out put returned into utf-8 and now the characters can be seen in the datatables. Hope it helps somebody.